# Change default choice for onbeforeunload event

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

Is it possible to change the default option (if the user just presses enter) for the window.onbeforeunload event?  The popup button defaults to "leave this page" (at-least in Chrome), and I was wondering if there is a way, in the function, to change this default to "stay on page".

Comment: No, it's not possible to change the default option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to change the button selected by default in an exit dialog without making a change to the user's web browser itself.